# Disable HDMI sound output when using optical (TOSLINK) output on AppleTV

Tags: appletv, hdmi

I have Apple TV and have both HDMI and TOSLINK (optical) port connected. But the problem is that when i turn on the video via Apple TV I have double sound from the sound - from the TV set connected via HDMI and the sound system connected via TOSLINK. The later is deleyed due to the fact that TOSLINK is coverted RCA.  This makes me turn off sound in the TV set.

Is there a way to not transmit sound via HDMI in Apple TV if it is anyway transmited to TOSLINK?

Answer (score 5):

You could always use an HDMI cable that doesn't carry sound, not too expensive these days.

Comment: Despite having a negative vote, this is a valid answer to the question. This *would* disable HDMI sound. Sure, it would be a permanent disabling, but it would disable the sound.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to disable HDMI sound output on Apple TV. The only solution is to mute sound on the TV itself, so you only hear audio from the receiver (sound system).

Answer (score -2):

not sure about your TV but mine has a setting to turn the speakers off on the TV. I never use them anyway - everything runs through my surround sound

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. While your answer provides a work-around, it does not answer the question posed and is duplicative of the answer previously given.